# How to implement a Cocktail Shaker Sort in Python to sort through the price of books?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to create a function that takes a list of books, a string indicating whether to sort by price or quality, and a boolean that will indicate that sorting should be in ascending order. I have faced an issue of not understanding why the code bellow is not returning the list of books sorted by price.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
def shakerSortBooks(book_lists, type_of_sort, ascending):
    start = 0
    end = len(list_book) - 1
    while start < end:
        for i in range(start, end):
            for j in range (start, end - 1):
                if book_lists[j][type_of_sort] > book_lists[j + 1][type_of_sort]:
                        book_lists[j], list_book[j + 1] = book_lists[j + 1], book_lists[j]
        for i in range(end - 1, start - 1, -1):
            for j in range (i):
                if book_lists[j][type_of_sort] > book_lists[j + 1][type_of_sort]:
                    book_lists[j], list_book[j + 1] = book_lists[j + 1], book_lists[j]
        return book_lists
```

Comment: What is the structure of *book_lists*? Is it a list of dictionaries or a list of lists or something else. Maybe show some sample data with expected output